# How to break a date from ACF?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, date

I need to print the number in one font, and the year in another

```
 <?php $timestamp = get_field('date_time'); ?>
```

How to do it . help me please

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. For formatting dates and times you can find examples in the PHP `date()` documentation, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. And please note that 3rd party plugins, such as ACF, are considered off-topic here on WPSE. It is highly recommended to contact the plugin author should you have any questions regarding the use and/or configuration of the plugin.

Comment: thank you  very match))))

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get separated data from timestamp using `date();` function. you can apply different fonts each value.

```
 <?php 
    $timestamp = get_field('date_time');

    $day = date('d', $timestamp);
    $mon = date('m', $timestamp);
    $year = date('Y', $timestamp);

    echo "Day : ".$day."<br>";
    echo "Month : ".$mon."<br>";
    echo "Year : ".$year;
?>
```

if `$timestamp` value "`1567503270`" then output will be below.

**Output :**

```
Day : 03
Month : 09
Year : 2019
```

if `get_field('date_time')` return `15 june, 2019` then its timestap will be `1560629940`. see below code for reference.

```
$timestamp = strtotime("15 june, 2019");

$day = date('d', $timestamp);
$mon = date('m', $timestamp);
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);

echo "timestamp : ".$timestamp."<br>";
echo "Day : ".$day."<br>";
echo "Month : ".$mon."<br>";
echo "Year : ".$year;

**Output**

timestamp : 1560629940
Day : 15
Month : 06
Year : 2019
```

Comment: thank you very match))))

Comment: You're Welcome!

Comment: But if $timestamp  value 15 june, 2019 ?

Comment: then you have to convert date into timestamp first. $timestamp = strtotime(get_field('date_time'));

Comment: he still infers 1970 for some reason.does not work anyway

Comment: i have update my answer with your date 15 june, 2019.

Comment: I really don’t understand why then it doesn’t work.
I do as you wrote and it doesn’t output anything $timestamp

Comment: check your get_field('date_time'); is empty or not.  try to print value of get_field('date_time');. what data returns?

Comment: it's return 15 июня, 2019

Comment: июня is create problem here. date()  can not consider июня as month so it will return invalid. can you save month as June not июня?

Comment: the fact is that I would have to save the date not in English but in another language ...

Comment: I do everything in the Russian admin panel, but then I will need to display the date in Latvian